# PHP form-calling function failing to work properly

Tags: php, forms, function

I have my index.php form and if a valid student name and student number are entered I'd like *"Student name and number are valid."* to be echoed.

I have validated the student names and student numbers.  However, even when entering a valid student name and student number the message echoed is *"The information you have entered is not valid.  Please enter your information again."*

I'm calling the **function validateStudent** but I must be calling it in the wrong place or incorrectly.  This function is called towards the end of the PHP scrip and just before the HTML starts.  Thank you.

> 

```html
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

// Define and set variables 
$student = ""; 
$studentname = ""; 
$studentnumber = ""; 
$studentfile = "student.txt"; 
$course = "";
$coursename = ""; 
$coursenumber = ""; 
$coursemax = 0;
$coursefile = "course.txt"; 
$in = fopen ('course.txt', 'r') or die ("course.txt cannot be opened for reading."); 

// Sanitization and Validation coding will go here 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $studentname = $_POST['studentname']; 
    $studentnumber = $_POST['studentnumber']; 
} 

if (isset($_POST['studentname'])) {
    $studentname = strip_tags ($_POST['studentname']); 
    $studentname = htmlentities ($_POST['studentname']); 
}

if (isset($_POST['studentnumber'])) {
    $studentnumber = strip_tags ($_POST['studentnumber']);
    $studentnumber = htmlentities ($_POST['studentnumber']); 
}

if (isset($_POST['course'])) {
    $course = strip_tags ($_POST['course']);
    $course = htmlentities ($_POST['course']); 
}

$studentname = trim($_POST['studentname']);

$studentnumber = trim($_POST['studentnumber']);


// Validate student name/number against text file  
function validateStudent($studentName, $studentNumber) 
{ 
    $found = false; 
    $fh = fopen('student.txt', 'r'); 
    while(($line = fgetcsv($fh, null, ':')) != false) { 
        if(count($line) > 1) { 
            if($line[0] == $studentName and $line[1] == $studentNumber) { 
                $found = true; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $found; 
} 

// Validate course name/number against text file 
function validateCourse($courseName, $courseNumber, $courseMax) 
{ 
    $found = false; 
    $fh = fopen('course.txt', 'r'); 
    while(($line = fgetcsv($fh, null, ':')) != false) { 
        if(count($line) > 1) { 
            if($line[0] == $courseName and $line[1] == $courseNumber and $line[2] == $courseMax) { 
                $found = true; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $found; 
} 


//$DB = fopen ($coursefile, 'r') or die ("$coursefile cannot be opened for reading.");
 //while ($record = fgets ($DB) ) {
    //$field = explode (":", htmlentities (trim ($record)));
    //echo "<option value=\"$field[1]\">$field[0] $field[1] $field[2]</option>\n";
 //}
 //fclose ($DB);
 

if (isset ($_POST[$studentname], $_POST[$studentnumber])) {
            validateStudent($_POST['$studentname'], $_POST['$studentnumber']);
            echo 'Student name and number are valid.\n';
        }
        else {
            echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">**The information you have entered is not valid.  Please enter your information again.**</p>';
        }

  
?> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Registration Form</title> 
    <style> 
        body{background-color: #ffffe6; width:610px;} 
        h1 {color: #29a3a3;} 
        .inputbox {padding: 7px; border: #FF9966 1px solid; border-radius: 4px;} 
        .btn {padding: 10px; background-color: #29a3a3; border: solid 1px #FF9966; border-radius: 4px; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bolder; cursor: pointer;} 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Course Registration</h1> 
<form method="post" action="index.php"> 
    <fieldset><legend><strong>Student Information</strong></legend> 
        <dl> 
            <dt>Student Name:</dt> 
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentname" type="text" id="studentname" value='<?php echo htmlentities($studentname) ?>' required autofocus placeholder="Please enter your first and last name" tabindex="10" size="50"></dd> 
            <br> 
            <br> 
            <dt>Student Number:</dt> 
            <dd><input class="inputbox" name="studentnumber" type="text" id="studentnumber" value='<?php echo htmlentities($studentnumber) ?>' required placeholder="Please enter using the following format: PX-03-046" tabindex="20" size="50"></dd> 
        </dl> 
        <br> 
    </fieldset> 
    <br> 
    <fieldset><legend><strong>Course Selection</strong></legend> 
        <br> 
        Select a Course:<select name="course" tabindex="30">\n"; 
            <option value="-1" >Available Courses...</option> 
                <?php 
                while(($fields = fgetcsv($in, null, ':')) != false) { 
                    if (count($fields) > 1) { 
                        echo " 
                            <option value=\"$fields[1]\">$fields[0] $fields[1]</option>"; 
                    } 
                } 
                ?> 
        </select> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
        <br> 
    </fieldset> 
    <div> 
        <p> 
            <input name="reset" type="reset" tabindex="40" value="Clear Form" class="btn"> 
            <input name="submit" type="submit" tabindex="50" value="Submit Form" class="btn"> 
        </p> 
    </div> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite $studentnumber & $studentname with $_POST data? None of your previous sanitising functions have any affect.

Comment: Hi Gavin,  I should have indicated I'm very, very new to PHP and am very much in the learning stage.  So by doing this I've nulled the sanitizing code near the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logical error:

```
if (isset ($_POST[$studentname], $_POST[$studentnumber])) {
            validateStudent($_POST['$studentname'], $_POST['$studentnumber']);
            echo 'Student name and number are valid.\n';
        }
        else {
            echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">**The information you have entered is not valid.  Please enter your information again.**</p>';
        }
```

your code should be:

```
if (isset ($_POST['studentname'], $_POST['studentnumber'])) {
     if (validateStudent($_POST['studentname'], $_POST['studentnumber'])){
         echo 'Student name and number are valid.\n';
     }
     else {
         echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">**The information you have entered is not valid.  Please enter your information again.**</p>';
     }
}
```

also you need a form to post your variables studentname and studentnumer like:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="studentname"/>
   <input type="text" name="studentnumber"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Your output is because your variables `$_POST['studentname']` and `$_POST['studentnumber']` are not set.

Comment: Hi Panda and thank you.  It's a very steep learning curve for me.  I changed my code to match yours and had the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Users\HP Pavilion\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 94 which is this line [code]if (validateStudent($_POST['$studentname'], $_POST['$studentnumber']){[/code]

Comment: Hi Christine, sorry, I forgot a "(" there. Try this:          if (validateStudent($_POST['$studentname'], $_POST['$studentnumber'])){
             //....

Comment: Hi Panda, no sorry necessary - I appreciate the help.  It's not returning the error message but neither one of the echo statements displays.

Comment: I saw a huge mistake, which we made.. xD the if isset statement should be  [code]if (isset ($_POST['studentname'], $_POST['studentnumber'])){ [/code] now it should work. $_POST[$studentname] is clearly wrong.. I didn't see it. fixed it in my original answer

Comment: Panda... that works like a charm!  Thank you bunches!  : )